# TextField Loses Focus After Each Character Input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, focus, textfield

I am having an issue with my React application where I am unable to type a complete sentence at once in a TextField. When I try to type, it just types one character and then loses focus. I have to click back into the text field after each character to type the next one.

Here's the part of my code that deals with the TextField:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

export default function Edit() {
  const [serialNumberPairs, setSerialNumberPairs] = React.useState([
    { serial_number: "", nickname: "" },
  ]);

  const handleNicknameChange = (event, index) => {
    const newSerialNumberPairs = [...serialNumberPairs];
    newSerialNumberPairs[index].nickname = event.target.value;
    setSerialNumberPairs(newSerialNumberPairs);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {serialNumberPairs.map((pair, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <TextField
            label="Nickname"
            value={pair.nickname}
            onChange={(event) => handleNicknameChange(event, index)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above handleNicknameChange function is triggered when I type into the TextField. After each change event, I create a new array of serialNumberPairs and update the state using setSerialNumberPairs. However, this causes the TextField to lose focus after each character input.

I've tried managing the state differently, but the problem persists. Can someone please help me understand why the TextField loses focus after each character input, and how I can solve this issue?

This behavior only happens when the TextField is wrapped inside a scrollable styled-component box.The issue doesn't occur when the TextField is not inside the ScrollableBox, so it seems that the ScrollableBox is causing the problem. However, I don't understand why this is happening. I've tried debugging this by examining the rendered HTML and playing with the CSS, but I couldn't identify any problems.

```
// Relevant code
const ScrollableBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  height: "300px",
  width: "100%",
  overflow: "auto",
  border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[800]}`,
  borderRadius: "7px",
  "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
    width: "0px", // This will make the scrollbar invisible
  },
  "&:hover::-webkit-scrollbar": {
    width: "8px", // This will make the scrollbar visible on hover
  },
  "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
    background: theme.palette.grey[700],
    borderRadius: "4px",
  },
}));

// Inside render method
<ScrollableBox>
  {serialNumberPairs.map((pair, index) => (
    <TextField
      key={index}
      value={pair.nickname}
      onChange={(event) => handleNicknameChange(event, index)}
    />
  ))}
</ScrollableBox>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a key?  -> `<TextField key={index} .....   Not providing a key in debug mode in React for browser will give you a warning for this in the console.

Comment: I did. But it doesn't solve the problem @Keith

Comment: Are you able to knock up a snippet demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I just updated the code above. It works here but doesn't work in the main code from where i made the snippet from

Comment: @Suprava Could be problem with the parents code? Maybe you unmnout your Edit component. You can quickly check it with
```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am mounted");
    return () => {
      console.log("yep, I'm unmounted.");
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: That suggests your redraw issue is higher up.

Comment: I seem to have found the problem. Its due to the inclusion of a `Scrollable box`. Whenver the textfield is included in the scrollable box, i get that problem. I don't know how to fix it  @Gynekolog . I have updated the code